# javadoc in Groovy Grails Tool Suite

Tags: eclipse, groovy, ide

Anyone using Groovy IDE?

I can not enable javadoc in Groovy Grails Tool Suite.

When I set a javadoc location in Java Build Path for groovy-all artifact it validates it, but when I press OK it does not save for the project. So if I open again Java Build Path and look for javadoc location for the same jar - there will be epmty spase for javadoc location.

So how can I enable javadoc in Groovy Grails Tool Suite for Groovy-API?